# This version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

Linux CentOS

jdk = 11

SonarQube 9.1

Jenkinks 2.17

Jenkins's job use jdk 8

When I try to run Jenkins' job I get error:

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/EnvironmentInformation has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedClassloader.loadClass(IsolatedClassloader.java:82)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.DefaultBatchFactory.createBatch(DefaultBatchFactory.java:35)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.start(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart(EmbeddedScanner.java:220)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start(EmbeddedScanner.java:156)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:74)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The use of SonarQube 9.x requires the scanner to be run with at least Java 11. You're apparently running it with Java 8. That won't work.

Comment: For those coming in 2023+: More recent versions of SonarQube, for example 9.9, actually requires Java 17.

Answer (score 1):

New Sonarqube server version 9+ require Java 11.  So you have to install Java 11 on your machine and set path variables to match with Java 11.

> Tip - Restart your machine after changing Java 8 -> Java 11